# How do I cancel a half completed email configuration?

Tags: email, encryption

Phone is trapped trying to encrypt my device against my wishes.

On my Nexus S I was recently upgraded to 4.0.4 and decided to try adding my work email to my personal phone. This previously didn't work because Android didn't have the proper security settings. I previously did not have any other email accounts setup.

Did an manual setup for an Exchange server and it prompted me to give the email app additional permissions (enforce lock screen, full device encryption etc.) I accepted and configured the lock screen as requested. The full device encryption page popped up and it informed me that once encrypted I would not be able to decrypt the device without a factory reset. I was not interested in that, but there is no cancel button on the encryption warning page.

I quit to the home screen, but now the phone constantly reminds me to complete the account setup.

Is there a way to cancel the account setup? What are my options? I'd prefer not to have to do a factory reset.

Did Google really place the warning page in a time where it's already too late to do anything or have I missed some other way to cancel? Every time I open the email app it says that the email account requires I change my security settings. I can cancel and the app closes or accept and the encryption page appears.

Comment: Naturally, I figured it out 10 minutes after posting. Can't answer for another few hours because I'm a new user. 



Under the security section of the settings, there is a Device Administrator page. I deactivated the "Email" app as an admin. It warned that it would delete all my mail and stuff and I accepted.


No factory reset required.


Thank you Stack Exchange for allowing me to express my question so I could figure it out myself :)

Comment: I'm sure that you're not the only who has been caught by that, or will be in the future. Yes, please do add your findings as an Answer and accept it so future readers can benefit.

Comment: Glad you found something that worked.  I'd have recommended finding the Email app in the "App Settings", forcing it to stop, then clearing its data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reposting answer for future people!

Naturally, I figured it out 10 minutes after posting.

Can't answer for another few hours because I'm a new user. Under the security section of the settings, there is a Device Administrator page.

I deactivated the "Email" app as an admin. It warned that it would delete all my mail and stuff and I accepted. No factory reset required.

Thank you Stack Exchange for allowing me to express my question so I could figure it out myself :)